# Column validation based on another column

Tags: column, validation

I have a list where users can fill a column named "External effort (m/d)" (type of column is number). After that column, I have "External resource cost" column, which type is currency, and where users can write a cost of resource.

I would like to do a column validation, where if the column "External effort (m/d)" is filled, then it's required to fill "External resource cost" column.
How would that function look for that column validation?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use the SPServices Library [Here](http://spservices.codeplex.com)
and within the `document.ready` function, get those field names and perform the validation/manipulation.

You can use a `Content Editor WebPart` and refer the `.js` libraries and add the code.

Also You can use SharePoint Designer to add the code and perform the SPField manipulation.

Comment: It won't be a problem if i have different content types in list? pic: pho.to/9vojC These two columns are in Planning phase, and if I close planing phase workflow automatically opens next phase.

Comment: if you use SPServices library, you can access the columns any point of time and whether the columns are within the  content types or not. May be you can put a if condition whether the phase field is planning or closed etc.

Comment: No need for loading extra stuff like jQuery or SPServices. SharePoint has mQuery and the PreSaveAction. Or go with CSR (on 2013)

Comment: @Danny, Can you pls elaborate, whats mQuery?

Comment: There is this great website called www.Google.com ; you can type what you want to know and it will search (almost) the whole world for you. Has been around since 1998 or so.... But hey I am a nice guy.. [click here](https://www.google.nl/search?q=mquery&tbs=qdr:y&tbo=1&as_oq=sharepoint&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=R6JyVoHeBcKsPtX5tvAF)

Comment: @Danny, thanks for the valuable info. :-) I got some info on mQuery, its clone of jQuery optimized for mobile clients.